# Is it possible to disable ALL tooltips in Texstudio?

Tags: texstudio

I would like to be able to disable ALL tooltips in TexStudio. I have been to:

> Shortcuts >> Show Shortcuts in toolTips

> Adv. Editor >> Show image tooltip and show help as tooltip

> Completion >> ToolTip-Help and Tool-Tip Preview

> Preview >> Show preview as tooltip

and disabled all of these but I am still getting tooltips in Syntax Highlighting and In the structure window and when I hover over any icon in the toolbars.

Is there anyway to disable ALL of these?

I am on ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

The way I did this was to disable all tooltips in Ubuntu 18.04 using this link: [Disabling Mouseover Tooltips](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094829/disabling-the-mouse-over-tootips).

It would be cool if I could disable only TexStudio tooltips from inside TexStudio.

Comment: Your question here will not be read by many people, better would be to edit your question and add aditional infos there ...

Comment: @Mensch I think this is an answer, not a question (or at least a partial answer).